# How would I call only one variable from a function that contains multiple variables?

Tags: python

So basically I am trying to create a hangman game, and as of right now I'm just trying to pass a variable from one function to another, though I'm confused on how to do so, here is my code:

```
import random

print("Welcome to Hangman!")

def wordSelection():
  words = ["test", "random"]
  wordChoice = random.randint(0, 1)
  selectedWord = words[wordChoice]
  print(selectedWord)
  return selectedWord

def guessWord():
  selectedWord = wordSelection()
  print(selectedWord)


wordSelection()
guessWord()
```

The question I have is basically, how am I able to call the variable `'selectedWord'` from the `wordSelection` function and pass it into the `guessWord()` function?

I tried to at the bottom as you can see, however I just called the whole function again, instead of only specifically getting `selectedWord` rather than the whole function.

What could I do to ONLY get `'selectedWord'` from `WordSelection()` rather than just getting the whole function - is this possible?

Comment: You can return values from functions, as you're doing with `selectedWord`, and store them in variables. You can pass these variables as parameters to other functions, when you call them. This could be a way of doing what you want, depending on your logic, it may work or not.

Comment: FYI you can call `random.choice(words)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding about how variables work, especially in Python.

In Python, a variable is simply a label that refers to a value that exists somewhere in memory. For example:

```
 x = 3
 # Now you can refer to the value `3` by the name x
 y = x
 # Now `y` refers to the *same* `3` that is in memory - it's not a copy!
 print(id(x))
 print(id(y))
 # Will print the same ID, but it will probably be different on your
 # system and mine
```

When you return a value from a function, you're not returning the name - you're returning effectively where the value lives. If you want to keep that value, you're going to have to give it a name:

```
def fun():
    result = 42
    print(id(result))
    return result

fun()  # Discards the return value
print(fun())  # prints the return value
print(id(fun))  # prints where the return value lives
value = fun()   # actually stores the return value by giving it a name
print(id(value))    # now you can use that value later!
print(value + 3)    # you can use it more times
```

So in *your* code, you want to call a function that gives you a random word, which you can do like this:

```
def word_selection():
    # Note I used snake case - see
    # https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names
    # for more info
    words = ['test', 'random', 'python', 'awesome', 'something', 'completely', 'different']
    return random.choice(words)
```

In order to do anything with this value, you need to store it. It's returned wherever you call the function. In Python you call something by adding parenthesis `()` after it:

```
print(word_selection)  # Doesn't call the function
print(word_selection())   # Does call the function, then prints the result
```

So you can either require an argument on your guess_word function and pass it in:

```
def guess_word(word):
    # do whatever you need to do here
    print('Time to guess:', word)   # don't really give them the answer, though

guess_word(word_selection())   # you can call it like this

secret_word = word_selection()   # or store the value first
guess_word(secret_word)          # and then pass it to your function
```

---

Writing your program like that is probably a good exercise in seeing how that stuff works - but you could actually make it the same by doing something like this:

```
WORD_LIST = ['python', 'something', 'completely', 'different']


def guess_word(word):
    print('Time to guess the word:', '*'*len(word))

guess_word(random.choice(WORD_LIST))
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but damn, this helped me a whole lot, thank you!

Comment: @HaashimFazal the commonly accepted way to express such a sentiment here on SO is to upvote (the triangle on the top) and, if it best answers your question, accept (click the checkmark, it will turn green). And, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the `selectedWord` value from `wordSelection()` so you can just directly use it in your code. Although, i don't understand what are you trying to accomplish with this as `guessWord` function is redundant.

You can do something like this :

```
guessWord(wordSelection())
```

and define `guessWord` function like this :

```
guessWord(words) :
```

This will pass the value returned by `wordSelection()` i.e. value of `selectedWord` in function `guessWord()`.

Answer (score -1):

Store the return value in a variable.

```
import random

print("Welcome to Hangman!")

def wordSelection():
  words = ["test", "random"]
  wordChoice = random.randint(0, 1)
  selectedWord = words[wordChoice]
  return selectedWord

def guessWord(selectedWord):
  selectedWord = wordSelection()
  print selectedWord
```

Comment: When I see an answer which starts with "try this" followed by a piece of code and doesn't explain what the code is supposed to accomplish I always downvote it.

Comment: @nbro, I will take care henceforth